# not able to create folders in aws s3 using boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I want to create a set of folders inside which i want to upload my file in s3 bucket.
However, i am not getting the required file names.
This is my code

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

def upload_to_aws(local_file, bucket, s3_file):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
                      aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)

    try:
        s3.upload_file(local_file, bucket, s3_file)
        print("Upload Successful")
        return True
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("The file was not found")
        return False
    except NoCredentialsError:
        print("Credentials not available")
        return False

customer_name = "demo"
date = datetime.now().strftime('%d')
month = datetime.now().month
year = datetime.now().year


stack_path = "/home/ubuntu/pano/stack"    
for file in sorted(os.listdir(stack_path)):
    print(f"Uploading {file}")
    folders_path = f"{customer_name}/{year}/{month}/{date}"
    uploaded = upload_to_aws(f'/home/ubuntu/pano/stack/{file}', 'bucket-name1', '%s/%s' % (folders_path, file))
```

I want the folders to be customer_name/year/month/date inside which i want the files ot be uploaded. However the folders i am getting are
"customer_name/ "
"year/"
"month/"
"date/"
I do not want the backslash in the folder name. how do i do this?

Edit

The folders i want has the following path - year/month/date/filename.txt
However the path that is being created have the following folder names
year//month//date//filename.txt

Each of the folder names has a backslash attached to it. Thesea re the directories i see in my bucket

1. year/
2. month/
3. date/

I want to avoid the backslash along with the names

Comment: There is no concept called "folders" in S3. These are prefixes to help grouping files. So, you can just upload file with `my/awesome/file/content.json` without ever explicitly creating the "folders".

Comment: In S3 you store objects with a Key. In theory it doesn't have folders. Can you give an example with a file name say "abc.txt" and explain what do you expect and what is happening?

Comment: All the comments above are true, but I still don't understand what is your issue. Could you explain it in more details?

Comment: @Azize I have added the details in the edit

Answer (score 2):

This is just a representation to show what is a "file" or what is a "folder".
But remember, there is no concept of folder, it is just an object key.

See below I am using your code. It succeeded to upload the files to bucket.

```
Python 3.8.0 (default, Feb 25 2021, 22:10:10) 
[GCC 8.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> import boto3
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> 
>>> def upload_to_aws(local_file, bucket, s3_file):
...     print("###", local_file, bucket, s3_file)
...     s3 = boto3.client('s3')
...     
...     try:
...         s3.upload_file(local_file, bucket, s3_file)
...         print("Upload Successful")
...         return True
...     except FileNotFoundError:
...         print("The file was not found")
...         return False
...     except NoCredentialsError:
...         print("Credentials not available")
...         return False
... 
>>> customer_name = "demo"
>>> date = datetime.now().strftime('%d')
>>> month = datetime.now().month
>>> year = datetime.now().year
>>> 
>>> 
>>> stack_path = "/tmp/test"
>>> for file in sorted(os.listdir(stack_path)):
...     print(f"Uploading {file}")
...     folders_path = f"{customer_name}/{year}/{month}/{date}"
...     uploaded = upload_to_aws(f'/tmp/test/{file}', 'test-bucket', '%s/%s' % (folders_path, file))
... 
Uploading file1
### /tmp/test/file1 test-bucket demo/2021/4/22/file1
Upload Successful
Uploading file2
### /tmp/test/file2 test-bucket demo/2021/4/22/file2
Upload Successful
Uploading file3
### /tmp/test/file3 test-bucket demo/2021/4/22/file3
Upload Successful
>>> exit()
```

Now let's see how to get the file. Note the key of the file is exactly what you expect, so not double `/` on it.

```
Python 3.8.0 (default, Feb 25 2021, 22:10:10) 
[GCC 8.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import boto3
>>> s3 = boto3.client('s3')
>>> s3.get_object(Bucket='test-bucket', Key='demo/2021/4/22/file1')
{'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'RE...', 'HostId': 'eMmV3p+...', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amz-id-2': 'eMm...', 'x-amz-request-id': 'RE..', 'date': 'Thu, 22 Apr 2021 13:45:33 GMT', 'last-modified': 'Thu, 22 Apr 2021 13:41:09 GMT', 'etag': '"355..."', 'accept-ranges': 'bytes', 'content-type': 'binary/octet-stream', 'content-length': '11', 'server': 'AmazonS3'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}, 'AcceptRanges': 'bytes', 'LastModified': datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 22, 13, 41, 9, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'ContentLength': 11, 'ETag': '"35..."', 'ContentType': 'binary/octet-stream', 'Metadata': {}, 'Body': <botocore.response.StreamingBody object at 0x7f2b2ea8ddf0>}
```

From AWS CLI. On the first output you can see the `/` in the end, but again it is just a representation, look the full object key below.

```
$ aws s3 ls s3://test-bucket/demo
                           PRE demo/

$ aws s3 ls s3://test-bucket/demo --recursive 
2021-04-22 10:41:09         11 demo/2021/4/22/file1
2021-04-22 10:41:09         11 demo/2021/4/22/file2
2021-04-22 10:41:10         11 demo/2021/4/22/file3
```